# google-like comparsion: "Did you mean *******?" - native PHP function

Tags: php, search

I know similar question was answered a lot times before, but I hope this is little bit releated, not a dupe.

Some time ago, I had some search-engine source code, and there was function which found similar words for inserted. It was NATIVE PHP FUNCTION.

Does anybody know similar function?
I found this one

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

but it is not EXACTLY what I mean.

Comment: Depending on where you get your data from you should let a dbms do it for it.

Comment: "dbms"? Do you think I'll google it?

Comment: I saw this extract in an example in your link: 

"I want to print out the value if it is 90 percent similar to the other one : the value is HE, the correct value is HEC. The similar_text() function will return approximately 66.7 %, and it will not print it because it is smaller than 90 %, although almost all of the string was matched."

Is that what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: @genesis: That would have been faster, than commenting here, because its in the title of the first, second and third hit. "DataBase Management System", or in simple: "database server".

Comment: so answer: yes, I want to use it with mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) maybe ?

Comment: wow, that's maybe correct! Do you think it's fine to be user with database output?

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific, I am afraid that I did not quite understood the question?

Comment: You answered my question, but next question is. Do you think I can use same function for mysql results output ?

Comment: I meant the second question when I said that I did not understand it :) . I do not see any reason why you should not be able to use it for your mysql result outputs. Just be careful that you need to have both strings limited to 255 chars.

Answer (score 0):

http://soundofemotion.com/spellcorrect.txt or maybe http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4859-PHP-Suggest-corrected-spelling-text-in-pure-PHP.html

i found them searching for the same in [python](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

Comment: yes, you asked for a native php function. i just remembered i saw something similar on a search i made for python, and i contributed, even if it wasn't "native" php. you don't need to be so harsh.

Comment: this isn't the appropriate place, so it'll be it. mine was just a suggestion, sorry if it was a bit off-topic by not being native. cheers.